# Post em tabela N:N com node.js e angularjs

Tags: angularjs, banco-de-dados, node.js

Tenho um relacionamento N:N e 3 tabelas: `projeto`, `pagamento` e `projeto_pagamento`. Em um formulário, quero cadastrar um projeto e 5 pagamentos, qual seria a melhor forma de realizar essa inserção?

Pensei em fazer um post em `projeto`, um post de um array em `pagamento`, depois pegar o ID do projeto e os IDs dos pagamentos em um array e fazer um post em `projeto_pagamento`. Ou seria melhor inserir cada pagamento separado ao invés de um array?

Dessa forma poderia usar um `forEach` na função de inserir pagamento e depois em `projeto_pagamento` também. Dá para retornar os IDs dos dados inseridos?

Comment: Você pode fazer o `POST` do objeto inteiro e tratá-lo da forma que convir no servidor

Comment: Interessante, não tinha pensado desta forma. Em questão de segurança e boas práticas isso seria legal?

Comment: Nunca parei pra pesquisar, mas eu prefiro fazer dessa forma pra "economizar" requisições e processamento no client

Comment: Muito bom, vou testar assim, mas como é uma `api` eu devo fazer o post em qual `endpoint`? Pode ser em `/projetos` ou `/pagamentos` mesmo? Ou crio outro `endpoint` para este caso específico, já que será necessário fazer um insert em cada tabela?

Comment: Pode ser `/projetos` mesmo